# Iterate Object Literal to populate a list

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out how to get this working:

```
export const countries = {
    AFGHANISTAN: {
        countryId: 0,
        name: "Afghanistan"
    },
    ALBANIA: {
        countryId: 1,
        name: "Albania"
    }
}|
```

Then try to iterate that and return some options:

```
export const countryOptions = () => {
  let countryOptions = [];

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(countries)) {
    const dropdownOption = {
      text: {
        type: "plain_text",
        text: {value.name}
      },
      value: value.countryId
    }

    countryOptions.push(dropdownOption);
  });

  return countryOptions;
}
```

it's not quite right, I don't know how to reference `name` and `countryId` properly here.

I don't think you can use a `map` on this because it's not an iterable like that, so that's why I'm trying via `Object.entries()`.

Comment: `{value.name}` is invalid syntax. Change to `value.name` and it looks reasonable to me?

Comment: You *could* use `map()` on the array that `Object.entries()` or `Object.values()` return.

Comment: @CertainPerformance why did you delete your answer, I was going to accept it because I like how you allowed .map again on it.

Comment: I realized the first part was wrong (the `Object.entries` returns an array, not a generic iterable), so I deleted the answer for a minute to fix it, but then the question was deleted and I was unable to undelete the answer then. Undeleted now

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by CertainPerformance, you have `{}`'s extra.

```
Object.entries(countries).map(([key,value]) => ({
text:{
  type: "plain_text",
  text: value.name
}
}))
```

This is just a fancier version of your code. :)

Comment: thanks, I guess I should have tried that first.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries` returns an array, on which `.map` can be used. But here, you only care about the values, not the keys, so use `Object.values` instead:

```
export const countryOptions = () => Object.values(countries)
  .map(obj => ({
    text: {
      type: 'plain_text',
      text: obj.name,
    },
    value: obj.countryId
  }));
```